# iOS/Android policy on third party network libraries over mobile data

Tags: android, ios, html, qt, mqtt

Was recently evaluating third party libraries for the potential for using MQTT on mobile devices. I ran across this quote: (https://github.com/relayr/apple-mqtt-example) "Apple forbids the use of third party networking libraries from using the mobile internet antenna."

So this means you'd have to use a library that "wraps" native API calls.

If this is true, how would you implement an MQTT client in x-platform frameworks such as Qt?
Take, for example a QT client: https://github.com/emqtt/qmqtt/blob/master/qmqtt_network.cpp
Would qmqtt not be permitted access to mobile data? Would you have to assume QTCPSocket binds to a native call?

In  HTML5/Hybrid solutions, would using a javascript client library such as paho over web sockets use the OS's browser api, and therefor be blessed?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html Related Apple doc

Answer (score 0):

From within an HTML5/Hybrid application, you can use the Internet connection (you should use the required config for that). As such, using a JavaScript MQTT client (Paho for instance) should work.